# PHP json_encode Problem with Backslash and Array Name

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, json

I'm converting some postgresql data to PHP json_encode, but I have some problems:

- json_encode adds an BackSlash to all slashes that I have in my data.
- In descriptions apears the close of paragraph tag , i think because the backslashes problem...
- and i don't want my array inside the object named with index "0" but with the name "attach:"

**MY JSON OUTPUT:**

```
{"arns":[{"arn":"CSC-ECN-NAUB109","problem":"description problem<\/p>",
"solution":"solution description<\/p>",
   "0":[{"name":"jquery.png","path":"http:\/\/arn.test.pt\/uploads\/CSC-ECN-NAUB109\/jquery.png"}]}]}
```

**MY CODE:**

```
<?php 

require('includes/connection.php');

$modelos_info = (isset($_GET['models'])) ? $_GET['models'] : "none";

if($modelos_info != "none"){

$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM arn_info JOIN upload2 ON (arn_info.arn=upload2.id_arn) WHERE modelos LIKE '$modelos_info ;%' OR modelos LIKE '%; $modelos_info ;%' ");

$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$response = array();
$posts = array();

while($row = $sth->fetch())
{ 

$arn=$row ['arn'];
$problem=$row['problem'];
$solution=$row['solution'];
$name=$row['name'];
$path=$row['path'];

$posts_anexos['attach'] = $posts2;

$posts2[] = array('name'=> $name , 'path'=> 'http://arn.test.pt/' .$path);
$posts[] = array('arn'=> $arn , 'problem'=> $problem , 'solution'=> $solution, $posts2 );
} 

$response['arns'] = $posts;

$fp = fopen('arns.json', 'w');

fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));

fclose($fp);

echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the first point, if I try doing this :

```
$str = "this / string";
var_dump(json_encode($str));
```

I get :

```
string '"this \/ string"' (length=16)
```

With backslashes too.

Looking at [**json.org**](http://json.org/), it seems the JSON standard defines that slashes, inside strings, should be escaped.

So, `json_encode()` seems to be doing the right thing.

If you do not want those slashes to be escaped, then, you don't want valid-JSON, and should not work with `json_encode`.

---

For the second point, now, you should not use this :

```
$posts[] = array(..., $posts2 );
```

Instead, you should use :

```
$posts[] = array(..., 'attach' => $posts2 );
```

This way, that last element of the array will have the 'attach' name.

Comment: Yes, you're right in two points, Any suggestion to use instead json_encode ?

Comment: No real suggestion, no : using valid-JSON is probably a better solution than re-inventing the wheel, trying to rewrite something.

Comment: Or if you're using PHP >= 5.3.0, use `json_encode($posts, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`

Comment: Thanks, no I'm using 5.2.5. I solve the problem with other post, $json_encoded_string = json_encode($response);
$json_encoded_string = str_replace("\\/", '/', $json_encoded_string);

Comment: Forward slashes *can* be escaped, then don't have to be (just like you can write an 'a' as '\u0061'. Backslashes and double quotes need to be escaped (since they're significant in other parts of the grammar (namely, escaping and closing strings, and control characters), but the other characters don't need to be. The grammar given in the RFC - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt - has it explicit.

Comment: PHP still doesn't seem to handle escapes properly for backslashes.  JSON with a "\" fails to parse if whatever comes after the backslash isn't valid.  However, "\\" parses straight through as "\\".  So seemingly there's no way to represent a single backslash?