# Why is json_encode adding backslashes?

Tags: php, json

I've been using `json_encode` for a long time, and I've not had any problems so far.
Now I'm working with a upload script and I try to return some JSON data after file upload.

I have the following code:

```
print_r($result); // <-- This is an associative array
echo json_encode($result); // <-- this returns valid JSON
```

This gives me the following  results:

```
// print_r result
Array
(
    [logo_url] => http://mysite.com/uploads/gallery/7f/3b/f65ab8165d_logo.jpeg
    [img_id] => 54
    [feedback] => Array
        (
            [message] => File uploaded
            [success] => 1
        )

)

// Echo result
{"logo_url":"http:\/\/mysite.com\/uploads\/gallery\/7f\/3b\/f65ab8165d_logo.jpeg","img_id":"54","feedback":{"message":"File uploaded","success":true}}
```

Can anyone tell me why `json_encode` adds slashes?

**update**

@Quentin said that something is happening between `json_encode` and `.parseJSON` and he's right.

Doing a `alert(data.toSource());` gives me the dollowing result:

```
({response:"{\"logo_url\":\"http:\\/\\/storelocator.com\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/gallery\\/7f\\/3b\\/71b9520cfc91a90afbdbbfc9d2b2239b_logo.jpeg\",\"img_id\":\"62\",\"feedback\":{\"message\":\"File uploaded\",\"success\":true}}", status:200})
```

And this is not valid JSON. It also adds the `status:200` and I have no idea where this comes from.

Could it be that the `Plupload bind` does something to my returned data?

This is my js script:

```
  uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, data) {
    alert(data.toSource());
    $('#' + file.id + " b").html("100%");
  });
```

Comment: Did you try to use search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272311/php-json-encode-problem-with-backslash-and-array-name

Comment: Yes, I have search and have seen various responses. The problem is that I'm not doing anything new that I've note already done a hundred times before in my code.

Comment: That "invalid" json looks like a bad attempt at a jsonp request, and not specifying the callback function name.

Comment: when i json_encode a json this happened !

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why json_encode adds slashes?

Forward slash characters can cause issues (when preceded by a `<` it triggers the SGML rules for "end of script element") when embedded in an HTML script element. They are escaped as a precaution.

> Because when I try do use jQuery.parseJSON(response); in my js script, it returns null. So my guess it has something to do with the slashes.

It doesn't. In JSON `"/"` and `"\/"` are equivalent.

The JSON you list in the question is valid (you can test it with [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)). Your problem is likely to do with what happens to it between `json_encode` and `parseJSON`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the circumstances? A link would be fine.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks. So JSON will always add slashes where needed. But jQuery's `parseJSON` still returns null. That tells me that the function receives an invalid string. So what can I do to figure this out?

Comment: @Steven — Looking at exactly what you are passing into parseJSON would be a sensible place to start. Then trace backwards from there.

Comment: I found the answer. The JSON was valid. I tried to do `$.parseJSON(response)`, but the correct way is `$.parseJSON(response.response)`. That did the trick. Plupload wraps the returned data inside `response` parameter.

Comment: One can disable this by setting the option JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

Answer (score 106):

Just use the "JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES" Option (added after version 5.4).

```
json_encode($array,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 43):

I just came across this issue in some of my scripts too, and it seemed to be happening because I was applying json_encode to an array wrapped inside another array which was also json encoded. It's easy to do if you have multiple foreach loops in a script that creates the data. Always apply json_encode at the end.

Here is what was happening. If you do:

```
$data[] = json_encode(['test' => 'one', 'test' => '2']);
$data[] = json_encode(['test' => 'two', 'test' => 'four']);
echo json_encode($data);
```

The result is:

```
["{\"test\":\"2\"}","{\"test\":\"four\"}"]
```

So, what you actually need to do is:

```
$data[] = ['test' => 'one', 'test' => '2'];
$data[] = ['test' => 'two', 'test' => 'four'];
echo json_encode($data);
```

And this will return

```
[{"test":"2"},{"test":"four"}]
```

Comment: This actually does not work for me. The result is "[{\"test\":\"2\"},{\"test\":\"four\"}]"

Comment: Are you using the sample code I've provided? See http://bit.ly/1OWrAdr at PhpFiddle.

Comment: You are right. Double json_ecoding will add those back slahses and also changed my array into string. @RicardoParro I had similar result as yours. Just json_encode once at the end.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the JSON format uses ""(Quotes) and anything in between these quotes is useful information (either key or the data).

Suppose your data was : `He said "This is how it is done".`
Then the actual data should look like `"He said \"This is how it is done\"."`.

This ensures that the `\"` is treated as `"(Quotation mark)` and not as JSON formatting. This is called `escape character`.

This usually happens when one tries to encode an already JSON encoded data, which is a common way I have seen this happen.

Try this

`$arr = ['This is a sample','This is also a "sample"'];
echo json_encode($arr);`

OUTPUT:

```
["This is a sample","This is also a \"sample\""]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your php script has the right header or it will add the slashes
header('Content-Type: application/json');

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I wanted an easy way to make my JSON output remove slashes and look pretty.

You can simply do this:

```
json_encode($value, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar problem, I had an array ready to be posted. in my post function I had this:

```
json = JSON.stringfy(json);
```

the detail here is that I'm using blade inside laravel to build a three view form, so I can go back and forward, I have in between every back and forward button validations and when I go back in the form without reloading the page my json get filled by backslashes. I `console.log(json)` in every validation and realized that the json was treated as a string instead of an object.

In conclution i shouldn't have assinged `json = JSON.stringfy(json)` instead i assigned it to another variable.

```
var aux = JSON.stringfy(json);
```

This way i keep json as an object, and not a string.

Answer (score -3):

`json_encode` will always add slashes.

Check some examples on the manual [HERE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

This is because if there are some characters which needs to escaped then they will create problem.

To use the json please Parse your json to ensure that the slashes are removed

Well whether or not you remove slashesthe json will be parsed without any problem by eval.

```
<?php
$array = array('url'=>'http://mysite.com/uploads/gallery/7f/3b/f65ab8165d_logo.jpeg','id'=>54);
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = jQuery.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($array);?>');
alert(x);
</script>
```

This is my code and i m able to parse the JSON.

Check your code May be you are missing something while parsing the JSON

Comment: In my `php.ini` magic quotes is set to OFF: `magic_quotes_gpc = Off`

Comment: The question clearly states that the JSON is being parsed with a proper JSON parser. Please don't recommend people use `eval`, we moved beyond it for JSON parsing years ago.

Comment: Hey bud check the code i m using. may be you r missing something.