# Google Apps API - php: refresh token has unexpected escape charactor

Tags: php, google-apps-script

After struggling for a day with why this was failing:

```
client->refresh($refresh_token);
```

(500 error), I discovered that the refresh token had an escaped forward slash:

```
"refresh_token":"1\/QnN3mTn_HPCaRwfpiCl11L0cT9u6z9ELb5URT4D_d6M",
```

Removing the backslash fixed the problem. Is this a problem with php or Google Apps API?

The above refresh token was returned from my php script as:

```
echo $client->getAccessToken();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that either your code or the library code decided to escape the token (possibly via `addslashes()`) at some point during the script's execution. It's not a problem with php per se, but an implementation issue.

**UPDATE:** 
It looks like the library is calling `json_encode()` on the result, which escapes slashes by default. According to another SO answer ([Why is json_encode adding backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes)), this is done to avoid problems when embedding JSON in HTML.

Now, the aforementioned answer also mentions that "\/" and "/" should be treated as equivalent by JSON parsers, so I am unfortunately unsure as to why Google Apps decides to slap you with a 500 in this case.

So in conclusion, you can say that
a) "It's a problem with the way PHP's `json_decode()` was designed to work. It shouldn't return escaped slashes by default."

b) "This is a problem with the Google Apps API service. It should treat "\/" and "/" as equivalent in JSON data."

c) "This is a problem with the Google Apps API library for PHP. Given that I'm sending `refresh()` the same, unchanged data returned by `getRefreshToken()`, it should perform the necessary mutations on the data to make it valid for the API call."

Unfortunately, this gets into matter-of-opinion territory, so I'm going to leave it at that.

Comment: Because I am echoing what is directly returned from the Google API call, I think it has to be in their library code.

Comment: Right you are, Sven. Take a look at my updated answer.