# Json Ouput for URL shows "image":"data\/demo\/hp_banner.jpg" in opencart

Tags: php, json, encoding, opencart

This is the output for echo json_encode. // uses `getBanner()` built-in function of opencart.

```
[
    {
        "banner_image_id": "77",
        "banner_id": "6",
        "link": "index.php?route=product/manufacturer/info&manufacturer_id=7",
        "image": "data/demo/hp_banner.jpg",
        "language_id": "1",
        "title": "HP Banner"
    }
]
```

The output in app is:

```
data\ /demo\ /hp_banner.jpg
```

The urls are what I am concerned about, as I have to use them on a Java App.

They can be fixed from java but I wonder why the URLs are that way?

Thank you

Comment: I think those are relative paths, i.e relative to the home directory of the application.

Comment: I am concerned with \ / in the URLs . Those will need extra code in java app to remove

Comment: But stack overflow is showing them properly but not in my app 
like data\/demo\/samsung_banner.jpg

Comment: This SO post should help you => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes

And the code to remove it is easy. Just use replaceAll("\\","")

Comment: I will have to modify in PHP?

Comment: Use a JSON Decoder on the Java side. It should take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSONObject class to decode the JSON at the client end. It will automatically remove those braces and slashes.