# json_encode adds backslashes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, json

I am getting some data from mysql and sending it to sever using json. But sending data as an array adds backslashes to my results.

PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT location_name, phone_number FROM location WHERE email_id = 'abc@gmail.com'");

$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $result_array[] = $row;
}
 echo json_encode($result_array);
```

JS:

```
    $$.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.abc.co/SupportData/get_business_locations.php', 
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                email: window.localStorage["email"]               
            },
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (jsonStr) {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
            }
        });
```

Output :

`[{\"location_name\":\"Bandra\",\"phone_number\":\"\"},{\"location_name\":\"Dadar\",\"phone_number\":\"\"},{\"location_name\":\"ee\",\"phone_number\":\"\"},{\"location_name\":\"ttttt\",\"phone_number\":\"\"}]""`

Comment: Use `json_encode($result_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` to remove  backslashes

Comment: I just removed `JSON.stringify` from JS and it worked perfectly. Still don't know why?

Comment: JSON.stringify turns an object in to a JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.Optional. Adds indentation, white space, and line break characters to the return-value JSON text to make it easier to read.

Comment: @Nehil, see answer below. It's because JSON.stringify effetively DOUBLE json_encodes your data, once in PHP and once in JS. If you want a JS object in your JS script, use JSON.parse, which will parse the JSON string to have into a JS object.

Answer (score 3):

```
stripslashes(json_encode($result_array))
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

To remove backslashes from json use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`

```
json_encode($result_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: try with `stripslashes(json_encode($result_array))`

Comment: Still same result. I guess it has something to `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the backslash by using the following code.

```
 str_replace("\ " , '' ,"jsonoutput");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that your AJAX call is already bringing back JSON. So if you do a JSON.stringify on top of that, you are effectively JSON encoding multiple times. See [Why is json_encode adding backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes/25245674#25245674), it may help.