# PHP saving file with \

Tags: php

I have string with `=`, instead of `\u003d`. I replaced it with `str_replace`. After that I saved it in json file. In file `\` was replaced to `\\` in `\u003d`. But if echo that string there is no `\\`. I tried to use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag, but it didn't help. What can I do to save file only with one `\`?
Code:

```
<?php
$value = PUT A RANDOM VALUE;
$value_base64 = base64_encode($value);
$value_replaced = str_replace('=', '\u003d', $value_base64);
//This array is just an example
$array = [
    "var1" => null,
    "var2" => array(
        "var2_1" => null,
        "value" => $value_replaced,
    )
];
$json = json_encode(ARRAY WITH $value_replaced AND OTHER VARIABLES, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

Variables in my case (I can't paste them here because they are too big):

```
[`$value (not url)`](http://pastebin.com/EJcxUaBR),
[`$value_base64`](http://pastebin.com/vJ9yH7GD),
[`$value_replaced`](http://pastebin.com/41zrsE1n),
[`$json`](http://pastebin.com/3TYRHUQT).
```

Comment: Can you share us your code?  your question is very obscure exposed like that...

Comment: what was the earlier text? whats does a replaced text looks like?

Comment: `str_replace` does not do any escaping, there must be something else you do that does the actual escaping. Two line example code that goes wrong would be easier for us to understand.

Comment: Please share your `str_replace` code.

Comment: In PHP, a literal backslash is matched with `\\\\\` (four back slashes).

Comment: @AshishChoudhary no that’s not true, you need four in regexes, as regexes in some cases does the escaping by themselves too (Hence some languages are using `//` instead of string for regexes). `str_replace` does not use regexes.

Comment: @Nitor Please put your code in your question, not in pastebin.com. Click the edit button underneath it.

Comment: Also make it short example, two lines example or whatever is the minimum you need.

Comment: Edited. All code pasted here is important.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes . The main problem is that preventing escaping of that \ makes little sense.

Comment: Oh, sorry for nitpicking more, but could you do something to that title of the question (“PHP saving file with \”), since the question seems to be about something totally else? For example “json_encode() adding double slashes when adding string with unicode letter” or something.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `json_encode` contains double `\` is because JSON syntax treats `\` as special symbol, which needs to be escaped. When you are passing `\u003d` to `json_encode()`, it thinks it to be just standard string that needs to be escaped.

When you are running `$value_replaced = str_replace('=', '\u003d', $value_base64);`, you are basically saying that instead of character `=`, you want your string to have 6 characters: `\u003d`. It will be then treated as so, causing `json_encode` to escape the backslashes where needed so the JSON will be valid.

When you run `json_decode()` for the result, backslashes will be converted to singular form again.