# Can not set the proper path for image using PHP

Tags: php, image

I need one help.I need to set the proper image path by joining two string using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$imagepath //=>http://localhost/crm/upload/
```

and my image path is like below.

```
$image //=>abc.jpg
```

when I am joining both to get total path like below and set the path in a array.

```
$totalpath=$imagepath.$image.
$data=array("data"=>array("image"=>$totalpath))
echo json_encode($data);
```

Its giving me the following output.

```
http:\/\/localhost\/crm\/upload\/abc.jpg
```

but I need the output like below.

```
http://localhost/crm/upload/abc.jpg
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is json\_encode adding backslashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode your json encoded data. Like below:

```
$imagepath ="http://localhost/crm/upload/";
$image ="abc.jpg";
$totalpath=$imagepath.$image;
$data=array("data"=>array("image"=>$totalpath));
$json_encode = json_encode($data);   
$json_decode = json_decode($json_encode, true);
$image = $json_decode['data']['image'];
echo $image; // http://localhost/crm/upload/abc.jpg
```

Comment: i am sending to $data to other user here i can not decode that.

Comment: @subhra other user how this data using? It needs to decode data on ther user end.

Comment: No,I solved this like this way `echo json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`,it gave me the proper result.