# Function Json_encode adds a \ behind every /

Tags: php, json

I am trying to edit some JSON files by using PHP with JSON enconde and JSON decode.

The JSON files has some URLs that obviously use '/'.

When I use JSON_decode and print the text, I get something like this:

```
url = http://www.example.com/something/hello_1.0;
```

Then I run this script:

```
$new['versions']        = array();
$new['versions'][$version]  = current( $decode['versions'] );
foreach( $decode['versions'] as $sVersion => $aVersion ) {
    $new['versions'][$sVersion] = $aVersion;
}
$decode['versions']= $new['versions'];
$encode = json_encode($decode,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

To add a new version, however the result is:

```
url = http:\/\/www.example.com\/something\/hello_1.1;
url = http:\/\/www.example.com\/something\/hello_1.0;
```

When I print the json_decode array, it still has the '/' correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: So what ? Is there a problem here ? This is just a way to escape special caracters.

Comment: Yes. The problem is that the JSON should look like: url = http://www.example.com/something/hello_1.0; or else it wont work

Comment: What won't work? To use the url you have to decode your JSON string and then you get the unescaped url anyway, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `json_encode` options to achieve what you want.
Especially the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` option is needed.
See [here](http://php.net/json_encode)

Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/something/hello_1.0;'
echo json_encode($url, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
//Prints: "http://www.example.com/something/hello_1.0;"
```