# PHP code adding backslash before forward slash

Tags: php, mysql

I have path stored in MySQL database.
Example

```
dir1/dir2/img1.jpg
```

When I run this function

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT path FROM walls WHERE category = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $cat);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($path);
            while($stmt->fetch()) {                 
                $url[] = $path;

            }
            echo json_encode($url);
```

it returns,

```
[[],"dir1\/dir2\/img1.jpg"]
```

Don't know why backslashes are adding up before forward slash.

Comment: It's a JSON issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10314758/1220930

Comment: What type of output do you want from `json_encode()`? Anything that supports JSON as input should handle the escaped slashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON` escapes all special characters by default. When decoded, you will get original value `dir1/dir2/img1.jpg`

You can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` to skip escaping slashes and is available since PHP 5.4.0

```
echo json_encode($url, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `json_encode` code, Use this following code for that purpose,

```
json_encode($url,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
echo json_encode($url, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

This will not escape slashes in directory path.