# php json_encode() automatically added slashes before slashes

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am storing my data in the form of json to the database. User can input with quotes, so i am manually adding slashes before the quotes. So my data becomes like this

```
array:8 [▼
  "buttonText" => "Large Button"
  "campName" => "Large\'s Button Test"
  "buttonSize" => "1"
]
```

But when i am converting it into json, the `json_encode()` function automatically added one more slash before my slash as

```
"{"buttonText":"Large Button","campName":"Large\\'s Button Test","buttonSize":"1"}"
```

Why the extra slash will be added, is there any option to prevent that

Comment: please provide more code. what you are experiencing usually happens due to implementing the json encode functions twice

Comment: You can take a look at : [Why is json_encode adding backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes)

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where you need to add slashes manually. I have the impression that you're trying to prevent SQL injection but you're instead corrupting data.

Comment: If you want to encode a value with a backslash, the correct JSON encoding for that is a doubled backslash. **Why are you adding backslashes to your data in the first place?!**

Comment: @ravisachaniya — That's about forward slashes, not backslashes.

Comment: If double quoted problem in query when storing  the data into database so you have to use the mysql_real_escape_string($data) or mysqli_real_escape($con,$data) function in php

Comment: *"Why the extra slash will be added, is there any option to prevent that?"* -- Do you want to prevent what? To prevent [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) create a valid JSON?  Go ahead and remove the backslashes as you please. You will come back tomorrow with another question complaining that [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) cannot decode your malformed JSONs.

Comment: @Always This is about escaping *backslashes*!

Comment: @axiac actually i am getting an array of objects when fetching the data in db, so i am striping the slashes for each object, but that extra slash is creating problem, i have to stripslashes two times

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR Thanks for approving my answer and if you still need to clean all slashes, here is also one my old solution what I post before 3 years ago: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php#114533

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you do like this? Is totaly bad thing adding slashes manualy.

You can just generate JSON using arrays like:

```
$arr=array();

$arr['buttonText']="Large Button";
$arr['campName']="Large's Button Test";
$arr['buttonSize']=1;

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Just use `json_encode()` to store values and `json_decode()` to get values.

Here is diferent aproach:

```
$arr=array(
    'buttonText'=>"Large Button",
    'campName'=>"Large's Button Test",
    'buttonSize'=>1,
);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

**[JSON ENCODE - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**

**[JSON DECODE - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)**

`json_encode()` adding slashes automaticaly and `json_decode()` remove it. You don't need to think about that. Just don't worry and be happy.

Answer (score 1):

Extra slashes are added because that's what `json_encode` will do. [See this documentation](http://php.net/json_encode)

In your case if you're encoding data to store in database, you don't need to manually add slashed. `json_encode` will take care of all escaping.