# Getting Data From Another Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

i'm just learning node.js, but i have little problem here, i want to use variable data from another function, in this code

```
var HOST = '162.144.36.40'
var PORT = 6969

net.createServer(function(sock) {
  console.log('TERKONEKSI: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
  sock.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('DATA: ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + data);
    sock.write('Anda mengirim "' + data + '"');
    var strData = data.toString();
    var arrData = strData.split(',');
    var sensorData = {
      'Nama_Sumur': arrData[0],
      'ID': arrData[1],
      'Temperatur': arrData[2],
      'Pressure': arrData[3],
      'Flowmeter': arrData[4],
      'Timestamp': arrData[5]
    };
  });
  sock.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('CLOSED ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':' + sock.remotePort);
  })
}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server sekarang listening di: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
var file = 'telemetry-data.json'
var obj = {
  "ID": 10,
  "Temperature": 27,
  "Pressure": 0.01,
  "Flow": 0.23,
  "Timestamp": 150595442
}

jsonfile.writeFile(file, obj, { flag: 'a' }, function(err) { console.error(err) })
```

My purpose is to writing to JSON file using arrData variable in above function. This is basic knowledge i guess, maybe just some clue to solve this.

Comment: what is your problem? `fs.writeFile` will allow you to write the file. But you have to do it in the same context where you have the date. Not outside the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use JSON.stringify to convert an array or values into a JSON formatted string.

JSON.stringify(sensorData);

Comment: Did you know why there is backslash in it ?

"{\"Nama_Sumur\":\"Batang_81\",\"ID\":\"10\",\"Temperature\":\"27.2\",\"Pressure\":\"0.01\",\"Flowmeter\":\"0.21\",\"Timestamp\":\"155984852\"}"

Comment: there is same problem    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes

Comment: and if this answer solved your problem then please tick answer as green tick sign.