# JSON.parse throws error if json has slashes

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I have a valid JSON that was generated using PHP `var json = <?php echo json_encode(['somearray']); ?>`.

In this array i have an html string, similar to below:

```
$myArray = ['image' => '<img src="/img/files/icon3.png" alt="" title="" />'];
json_encode($myArray);
```

For some reason, when I send above json to the JSON.parser I keep getting unexpected token error `"SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position XYZ"`

---

Example

```js
var json = '[{"id":8,"type":"dataFiles","name":"Noise Data Files","selected":{"data":{"id":1,"subscription_id":"3","filestorage_id":"1","title":"test 1","graph_type":"line chart","settings":{"band":"broadband","interval":"long","measurement":"1","time_interval":"","frequency":"","param":"","display":""},"created_at":"2018-07-03 21:46:08","updated_at":"2018-07-03 21:46:08","created_by":"5","page":"1","picture":"customers/3/dataviewer/nKvvMkRbKcU53mkflUdqIe8VUaRrM83EqpsiPNuc.png","pivot":{"project_element_id":"4","dataviewer_id":"1"},"type":"<img src=\"/img/dataviewer/icon.png\" alt=\"3\" title=\"Third\" />","name":"00014_C_110609_240118 (1).csv","instrument":"dBAir","serial_number":"67600","recorded_on":"2024-01-18 11:06:09"}},"set":true},{"id":2,"type":"freeText","name":"Free Text","selected":"Some text","set":true}]';

JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: Show us how exactly this is “send to” JSON.parse. Create a proper [mcve] that fully illustrates the problem, please, instead of showing single lines of code without proper context.

Comment: JSON.parse takes a string as an argument. your example shows an array of objects.

Comment: I am sending a string into JSON.parse

Comment: What is the backslash before the slash? I don't think it's needed.

Comment: The JSON you show here is valid.  So, that's probably not actually your JSON.

Comment: @חייםפרידמן It's called an escape character, and it's totally fine to be there.  Some JSON serializers produce this.

Comment: @Brad I know what is an escape charceter, but it's needed before a slash?

Comment: @חייםפרידמן See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes

Comment: @user3402600 Proof that your example is bad:  http://codepad.org/vv1VJYPG  Don't waste everyone's time if you haven't even narrowed the problem down yet.

Comment: @Brad Thanks. I didn't know this :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: I had to reinstall my php server so I could verify this, but I suspect you're doing this:

```
<script> 
  var json = '<?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>';
  JSON.parse(json);
</script>
```

Thing is, when you echo a `json_encode` directly into HTML like this, you don't need a `JSON.parse` at all, and you don't want to try to make it a string. Lose the quotes, and your `var json` will actually be the object, not a string. Like this:

```
<script> 
  var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>;
</script>
```

Notice no quotes around the `<? ... ?>`. And again, `myArray` won't be a string, it will be an array.

Comment: Nonsense, the only reason that's a problem is because you're creating string literals here in your answer rather than getting the JSON data from somewhere else.

Comment: @Brad take a look at the edit in the original post. He posted his actual generated javascript, and it's exactly what I said

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with your JSON serialization, or even really that it's JSON at all.  The problem is that you're pasting this in your code as a string literal.

When you have a backslash `\` in a JavaScript string literal (i.e., in your code), it serves as an escape character for example, `\n` resolves to a newline.

```
console.log('line 1 \n line 2`);
```

In your case, you're needlessly attempting to escape a forward slash with `\/` because you didn't escape that backslash in the first place.  That is, to put JSON directly in your code, as with any string that contains a backslash, you're going to have to double the backslashes to effectively cancel the escaping of the backslash in the first place.

So, `\/` becomes `\\/`, in your string literal.

None of this is an issue if you load your JSON from the server directly.  It's only a problem because you've pasted it into your code.

Comment: I suspect he's not pasting the code...he's probably doing something like `var t='<?php echo $var; ?>'`. (what I meant by PHP injection in my answer, which is probably the wrong term). An easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

I had to perform JSON.stringify() on the JSON that was sent to javascript via PHP. After which issue with / and other tokens have disappeared.