# How to decode a row from mysql database and encode it

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

I am trying to JSON decode row Options and encode it with rest of data. But it is only giving me Options row but. If I don't decode it give me this with backslashes in Options row.

> [{"ID":"4","AppID":"1","Question":"test2","Type":"Radios","OrderNumber":"2","Options":"{\"Number1\":
>   \"Yes\", \"Number2\": \"No\"}"}]

```
//open connection to mysql db

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbdata) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db

$sql = "select * from App_Questions";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row["Options"]){
        $str = json_decode($row["Options"]);
        $emparray = $str;
    }else{
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Comment: `If I don't decode`, why would you not decode the JSON string? What is in the DB, what do you have, what do you want? ... likely later question if the data is stored escaped, how are you writing the data?

Comment: what is the output of your current code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is json\_encode adding backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to decode the field "Options" which has json data saved to it, and then you want to encode those json data with rest of the other fields. The json decoded output is this from our question:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '4',
    'AppID' => '1',
    'Question' => 'test2',
    'Type' => 'Radios',
    'OrderNumber' => '2',
    'Options' => '{"Number1": "Yes", "Number2": "No"}',
  ),
)
```

If you decode "Options", you get this:

```
array (
  'Number1' => 'Yes',
  'Number2' => 'No',
)
```

You can do something like this to encode this with rest of the data inside the loop:

```
    $decodedData = json_decode($results);
    foreach ($decodedData as $row) {
        if (isset($row->Options)) {
            $decodedOptions = json_decode($row->Options);
            foreach ($decodedOptions as $key => $value) {
                $row->$key = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    $decodedData = json_encode($decodedData);
    print_r($decodedData);
```