# How can I convert a json web token into a json object?

Tags: php, jwt

I'm trying to decode my JSON Web Token into an JSON Parsed version,

but all it does is adding slashes to the string.

---

This is the code I'm testing it for:

```
<?php

$string = base64_decode("eyJpZCI6IDYsICJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkNsZW1lbnMiLCAiYXV0aGx2bCI6NX0");

$jsonObject = json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

echo $jsonObject;
?>
```

The data I want to get should be like:

```
[       
'id': 6,
'username': Clemens,
'authlvl': 5
]
```

But it changes it to this:

```
{"id": 6, "username":"Clemens", "authlvl":5}
```

Or this:

```
"{\"id\": 6, \"username\":\"Clemens\", \"authlvl\":5}"
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, I already tried many methods like these ones:

[Why is json_encode adding backslashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes/10314758)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKswJH7_plQ

Comment: The version you want isn't valid JSON (you can only have objects with named attributes), this `{"id": 6, "username":"Clemens", "authlvl":5}` is correct JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making a small mistake.

The base64 encoded data is already a JSONString so to make use of it in PHP you need to `json_decode()` it not `json_encode()` it

```
$string = base64_decode("eyJpZCI6IDYsICJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkNsZW1lbnMiLCAiYXV0aGx2bCI6NX0");
echo $string.PHP_EOL;
$jsonObject = json_decode($string);

print_r($jsonObject);
```

RESULT of echo

```
{"id": 6, "username":"Clemens", "authlvl":5}
```

RESULT of `print_r()`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 6
    [username] => Clemens
    [authlvl] => 5
)
```

**Alternatively** Just echo `$string`

```
$string = base64_decode("eyJpZCI6IDYsICJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkNsZW1lbnMiLCAiYXV0aGx2bCI6NX0");
echo $string.PHP_EOL;
```

RESULT, valid JSON

```
{"id": 6, "username":"Clemens", "authlvl":5}
```

Comment: To simple, Thanks you for this info!