# Laravel how to remove slashes when selecting json field from database using querybuilder

Tags: php, json, laravel

Basically I got a `json` field in my database which is a valid json format. When I paste the json field in the json viewer I got something like

```
"priceByBlock":[
      {
         "maxArea":6049,
         "minPrice":"$4,455,000",
         "unitNum":102,
         "maxPrice":"$35,000,000",
         "type":"Block 86",
         "minArea":1313
      },
      {
         "maxArea":5683,
         "minPrice":"$9,922,000",
         "unitNum":52,
         "maxPrice":"$33,000,000",
         "type":"Block 88",
         "minArea":2756
      }
   ],
   "priceByBedroom":[
      {
         "maxArea":6049,
         "minPrice":"$33,000,000",
         "unitNum":4,
         "maxPrice":"$35,000,000",
         "type":null,
         "minArea":5673
      },
```

But when I do a query like this based on laravel docs 
`->select('xp_ecoprop_summary.json->priceByBlock')`

I got something like

```
"json_unquote(json_extract(`xp_ecoprop_summary`.`json`, '$.\"priceByBlock\"'))": "[{\"type\": \"Block 
39\", \"maxArea\": 3003, \"minArea\": 614, \"unitNum\": 24, \"maxPrice\": \"$6,777,000\", \"minPrice\": \"$1,147,000\"}, {\"type\": \"Block 41\", \"maxArea\": 2842, \"minArea\": 614, \"unitNum\": 24, 
\"maxPrice\": \"$6,233,382\", \"minPrice\": \"$1,252,050\"}, {\"type\": \"Block 43\", \"maxArea\": 3003, 
\"minArea\": 614, \"unitNum\": 22, \"maxPrice\": \"$7,390,000\", \"minPrice\": \"$1,218,000\"}, 
{\"type\": \"Block 45\", \"maxArea\": 2842, \"minArea\": 614, \"unitNum\": 24, \"maxPrice\": 
\"$7,197,000\", \"minPrice\": \"$1,174,000\"}, {\"type\": \"Block 47\", \"maxArea\": 2325, \"minArea\": 
1539, \"unitNum\": 15, \"maxPrice\": \"$4,631,000\", \"minPrice\": \"$2,609,200\"}]"
```

I just want to return my json just like what the format did so that I can use it to loop in my tables like this `foreach price in priceByBlock` then `price.maxArea, price.minPrice` ans so on.

Comment: did try using json_decode?

Comment: try to use stripslashes()

Comment: tried using json_decode but the result returns as a string or same as the second one . @Poldo

Comment: nope i did not use `stripslashes` because in my db that is a valid json already. @AmalSR

Comment: This is not a valid json,  Also the json commnands how do they appear like the json_unquote, json_extract . Can you show us how you actually insert the json to the json column?

Comment: its here https://imgur.com/a/Amd9fg4 @pr1nc3

Comment: json result is here https://imgur.com/a/uc08uoP @pr1nc3

Comment: Can you show us then the full select query? Since you insert the json correctly the problem is in the select i guess. Does your model use casting to json or something cause inserted json and output json are not similar, somehow functions for json parsing are inserted in your select so you must have things in place that create conflicts.

Comment: no i dont use casting. @pr1nc3

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem. You can save your data as

```
json_encode($yourdata, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: so do you mean i need remove my old jsons and save it as like that? but in my database, there is no slashes.

Comment: @Vince Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314715/why-is-json-encode-adding-backslashes

Answer (score 0):

Juste replace the anti-slashes whit nothing

```
<?php
    $string = "json_unquote(json_extract(`xp_ecoprop_summary`.`json`, '$.\"priceByBlock\"'))": "[{\"type\": \"Block 
    39\", \"maxArea\": 3003, \"minArea\": 614, \"unitNum\": 24, \"maxPrice\": \"$6,777,000\", \"minPrice\": \"$1,147,000\"}, {\"type\": \"Block 41\", \"maxArea\": 2842, \"minArea\": 614, \"unitNum\": 24, 
    \"maxPrice\": \"$6,233,382\", \"minPrice\": \"$1,252,050\"}, {\"type\": \"Block 43\", \"maxArea\": 3003, 
    \"minArea\": 614, \"unitNum\": 22, \"maxPrice\": \"$7,390,000\", \"minPrice\": \"$1,218,000\"}, 
    {\"type\": \"Block 45\", \"maxArea\": 2842, \"minArea\": 614, \"unitNum\": 24, \"maxPrice\": 
    \"$7,197,000\", \"minPrice\": \"$1,174,000\"}, {\"type\": \"Block 47\", \"maxArea\": 2325, \"minArea\": 
    1539, \"unitNum\": 15, \"maxPrice\": \"$4,631,000\", \"minPrice\": \"$2,609,200\"}]"

    echo str_replace("\", "", $string);
```