# How to remove slash before and after my JSON string POST

Tags: php, flutter

Am using Flutter to POST an encrypted string I stored in my SharedPreference to my PHP JSON for some reason when I tried to retrieve the value to use and query database if such value is available it adds slash at the beginning and end of the value like this `"\"cbfddd256d9b5c5235f587415188ce2e36101c0c3269b6db398d4f53ad35898a\""`. I tried to trace it back to my Flutter code at the point of POST to see if that is where the extra slash came from but it wasn't there. Please can anyone help on how to remove the slash because my query returns null because of the extra slash

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10314715/4323201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are sending it to pop as a string with two quotes " " so php add the slash maybe try sending it without the " "

Answer (score 1):

This way you can remove the first and last character:

```
$sharePreference = substr($sharePreference, 1, -1);
```

other option, is applied a regex to extract the token:

```
$token ='\"cbfddd256d9b5c5235f587415188ce2e36101c0c3269b6db398d4f53ad35898a\"';
preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]+/', $token, $matches);

print_r($matches); // Array ( [0] => cbfddd256d9b5c5235f587415188ce2e36101c0c3269b6db398d4f53ad35898a )
```

Comment: where is $matches declared?

Comment: @mideveloper It's passed as third argument

Comment: @mideveloper take a look at documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php